# How to recompile all Sybase store procedures

Tags: sybase

We have more than 800 Sybase store procedures, we would like to recompile all. If I recompile one by one , it will take a lot of time. Sp_recompile  works only after next run, and you have to know what tables relate to procedure. I use alter procedure  recompile,syntax does not work on SQL. Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version are you running? `sp_recompile` is an ASE system proc while `alter procedure / recompiile` is a SQLAnywhere command ... `ASE != SQLAnywhere`